# Batteries in laptops

Tags: laptop, battery

I'm working with a customer that wants their Dell XPS M1730 fixed (I already tried convincing them that they should just get a new computer, but they are adamant on keeping this one). They were having issues with the battery not charging. My first go to was was either their charge port or the battery. Upon pulling their battery out I noticed that the battery compartment says "19.5 volts with 11.8 amps". The charger reflects this same information, their battery however is rated to 11.1 volts. I'm curious if their battery may have shorted or if the battery may have caused damage to the board. Sometimes the computer will boot up and display a screen that says that says the power adapter is wrong other times it won't boot. Every time it does boot thought it will just shut off at some random point. It will do this with the battery in the computer with and without the charger and with the just the charger.

I'm curious if someone else more versed in batteries might have an idea on what happened and what might need to get replaced other than the battery.

Comment: Batteries are typically not guaranteed more than 3 years so if it hasn't been replaced in over this amount of time & it's not keeping charged, they should get a replacement battery. If it is shutting down with NO BATTERY and plugged in the charger with that message, then take the enclosure off and inspect it for damage from heat, etc. Go ahead and dust it out while you can and be sure everything is tight and no obvious motherboard damage. If you can't figure it out, see how much to send in for repair and tell them that cost, your cost thus far, a new battery and maybe more later.

Comment: (cont...) Once you get it back, you can then inspect and tell them what further it may need. Give them the price point and timeline for this sort of repair, and then spec out an equivalent or better replacement, and have them weigh the cost. Also stress the importance of keeping valid warranty and extended warranty for laptops that they intend to keep long term as these things just go bad with age, heat, environment, etc. These are electrical, electronic, and mechanical parts so that's part of using the technology.

Comment: This seems to be a laptop from 2007 from my very quick research so this is a downside for using a laptop and of such age at that if it's been used regularly since purchase and normal wear and tear. If you cannot figure it out or see anything obvious or get it to stop the reboot so you can upgrade firmware and do further troubleshooting, see how much it costs to send to the Dell repair center or their 3rd party for products this age, etc. and give them the news... Start spreading the news!! You are a magic computer repair magician, right!!!....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The battery itself **is** rated at ~11.1 VDC (the 19 VDC of the charger is reduced to the battery voltage by the laptop's internal charging circuit), so that might *not* be the issue, but [replacements are available](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_19?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=dell+xps+m1730+battery&sprefix=Dell+XPS+M1730++bat%2Caps%2C223) for US$20 and up, if needed. Another suspect is the [CMOS/clock battery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLhgoBmO0EI), which could explain erratic startup.

First, though, try software fixes.

- [Dell has updated BIOS](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/Battery-plugged-in-not-charging-found-the-fix-that-worked-for-my/td-p/3929408) for various XPS models; see that the latest is installed.
- Reset charging:

  - In control panel, *Device Manager*, right-click on `Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery` and select *Uninstall device*.
    [image: Reset charging]
  - Shut down *completely* (disable fast/hybrid startup).
  - Remove the battery and power supply.
  - Hold down the power button for ~30 seconds.
  - Replace the battery and power supply.
  - Reboot.
  - Check the Windows has automatically reinstalled the ACPI charging driver -- if not, right click on *Batteries* and *Check for hardware changes*.

On one laptop, I needed to repeat that procedure, but on the second try, charging returned to normal.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try this and see where it gets me. Much appreciated.