# 2019 laptop, charges much faster and dies much faster, no previous battery problems, this was sudden

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, battery, battery-life

The estimated battery time left jumps from a few hours to a few minutes,my energy report says "The battery stored less than 40% of the Designed Capacity the last time the battery was fully charged." Though on top of other problems. I do not know if it could be the battery its self or drivers, the drivers with problems are in Chinese so I do not know how to update them or review them.

Comment: drivers? for the battery charging? like software drivers in whatever operating system you run? no, it's not drivers, it's probably a typical chinee 4 year old battery

Comment: you'll most probably need to get a new battery. If you can state  the exact model of your laptop, maybe someone can give you more precise information.

Comment: Charging is not controlled by software, it can only set some parameters on some laptops. // Do you know how many charging cycles the battery has lived through?

Comment: Before you buy a new battery, try *resetting* the charge status: https://superuser.com/questions/1338049/batteries-in-laptops